# How do I break patterns (#/space/capitalized letter) into a new line starting with the capitalized letter?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have 1000s of lines in Notepad++.  I need a Search and Replace formula that breaks lines with the following pattern:

**a single number/space/name that starts with a capital letter**

The resultant new line must begin with the capitalized letter of the name, so that …

```
Northern Harmony p,3,1:52.2 
SOME VINTAGE BEACH  
Mach Three p,3,1:49 Somebeachsomewhere p,3,1:46.4 -
Wheres The Beach Douknowwhereurgoin p,3,1:52.1
```

… becomes:

```
Northern Harmony p,3,1:52.2 
SOME VINTAGE BEACH  
Mach Three p,3,1:49 
Somebeachsomewhere p,3,1:46.4 -
Wheres The Beach Douknowwhereurgoin p,3,1:52.1
```

I can find the string in “**Find what**” using:        (?=[1-9] [A-Z])

But I can’t figure out the simpler task of what to enter into “**Replace with**” to create the new line starting with the capitalized letter of the name.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Are there only "normal" letters, or could there be also special ones, like accented ones (`À`, `Í`), for instance?

Comment: Hi aschipfl. There are no special characters in my data set.  I replaced the operative character (S) with your two examples and the suggested methods will not work with those special characters.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\d)\h*(?=[A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\n`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d)         # positive look behind, make sure we have a digit before
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?=[A-Z])       # positive lookahead, make sure we have a capital letter afer
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @mapman: You can use `(?<=\d)\ (?=[A-Z])` instead of `(?<=\d)\h*(?=[A-Z])` if you ar esure there is only 1 space. [It takes only 50 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2w2Qcr/1), using capture groups slows down the process, [it takes 308 steps](https://regex101.com/r/2w2Qcr/2). In short, avoid using capture groups when there aren't  mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use [capture groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups), and I don't think you need a lookahead. If you 'find'

```
([0-9]) ([A-Z])
```

(zero is a number too) and replace it with

```
\1\n\2
```

(the `\1` refers to the expression that matches the first group of parentheses, `\2` is the second group)
(also, be sure to choose the 'Regular expression' search mode)

[image]

you'll get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Ahh!  I don't know what I was thinking leaving out the 0.  Thank you, Glorfindel!